# Spring MongoDB sort with a custom expression over an array

Tags: spring, mongodb

Structure of documents:

```
{
  id: ObjectId("5ef1cd704b35c6d6698f2050")
  date: 2021-12-15T11:03:00.000+00:00
  priorityList: Array
    0: "any-String-id-here"
    1: ...
}
```

I'd like to find documents sorted by a custom expression with following conditions:

- At first documents containing a given string in their `priorityList`
- sorting by date

What I do

```
TypedAggregation<MyDocument> aggregation = newAggregation(MyDocument.class,
  project("id")
    .and("isInList").applyCondition(ConditionalOperators
        .when(Criteria.where("priorityList").all("here-my-string-to-check"))
        .then(1)
        .otherwise(0)),
  sort(Sort.by(
    Sort.Order.desc("isInList"),
    Sort.Order.desc("date"))));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my-collection-name", String.class);
```

produces

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: 
Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Invalid $project ::
caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$all''
```

How to implement the required sorting conditions?

Comment: Do you mean one of the elements of `priorityList` exactly matches `here-my-string-to-check`, or that one of the elements contains that string?

Comment: The first one: at least one of elements of the list exactly matches the given string

Comment: I don't think the `applyCondition` is needed.  If you project `{isInList:{$in:["here-my-string-to-check","$priorityList"]}}`, it will be boolean.

Comment: Your answer is what i exactly expect in the result query. The problem is i can not write such flexible expressions using spring framework. I can just use the given api